# Meteor.js Datatables Tabletools plugin

Tags: datatables, meteor, meteorite

I've got Datatables meteorite package working great in my Meteor.js app.  I need the copy to clipboard and print functionality that the Datatables Tabletools plugin provides ( http://datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/TableTools/swf_path.html ).  I have tried adding the library in several places and then initializing with the following but I'm not able to get it to work:

```
"sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
        "oTableTools": {
            "sSwfPath": "/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"},
```

Do I need to create a new meteorite package just for Tabletools or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0):

Use the datatables pugin inside the template render method

```
Template.quizzing.rendered = function () {
    $("#topic_lister").dataTable();
}
```

it is working here in ma project. hope will be helpful for u also.